# Permissions best-practices when using docker exec

Tags: docker

I am going through a docker course and have a simple Docker script which sets up an image:

```
FROM node:14.16.0-alpine3.13
RUN addgroup app && adduser -S -G app app
USER app
WORKDIR /app
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
ENV APP_URL=http://api.myapp.com
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Now, in the script it switches to `USER app` but when I log in to Docker exec using `docker exec -it 187 sh` I can ask it `whoami` and get the response: `app` which is correct. The problem comes when I try to write a file using the echo command:

```
echo data > data.txt
```

> sh: can't create data.txt: Permission denied

So then I run `ls -la` to view files and perms:

```
/app $ ls -la
total 1456
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          4096 Oct 20 16:38 .
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          4096 Oct 20 19:54 ..
-rw-rw-r--    1 root     root            13 Oct 20 13:46 .dockerignore
drwxr-xr-x    7 root     root          4096 Mar  9  2021 .git
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root           310 Mar  5  2021 .gitignore
-rw-rw-r--    1 root     root           311 Oct 20 16:38 Dockerfile
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          3362 Mar  5  2021 README.md
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          4096 Oct 20 16:38 node_modules
-rw-rw-r--    1 root     root       1434378 Oct 20 16:10 package-lock.json
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root           814 Oct 20 16:10 package.json
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 Mar  9  2021 public
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 Oct 20 13:22 src
```

Which shows that root is the user and group set for these files/dirs. This was obviously intended as we don't want to be logging in as root. So what should I do to be able to add this file to the container? What is the best practice here? Maybe I missed a step somewhere?

Edit: Should the `/app` be owned by the `USER app`? If so, what is the point in adding a new user? should I add this to the docker script:

```
RUN chown app /app
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Should the `/app` be owned by the `USER app`?

Definitely not.  You want to prevent the application from overwriting its own code and static assets, intentionally or otherwise.

> So what should I do to be able to add this file to the container?

Create a dedicated directory to hold your application's data.  This should be a different directory from the directory with the source code; a subdirectory of your normal application directory is fine.  In the Dockerfile, make this directory (only) be owned by your non-root user.

```sh
FROM node:14.16.0-alpine3.13
RUN addgroup app && adduser -S -G app app
# don't switch to this user quite yet
WORKDIR /app
# usual setup and build stuff
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm ci
COPY . ./
RUN npm build
# create the data directory and set its owner
RUN mkdir data && chown app data
# _now_ switch to the non-root user when running the container
EXPOSE 3000
USER app
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

In practice, you probably want to persist the application's data beyond the lifespan of a single container.  One approach to this is to use a Docker [named volume](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/).  If you do this, the volume will be initialized from the image, including its ownership, and so you don't need any special setup here.

```sh
docker volume create app-data
docker run -v app-data:/app/data ...
```

For several reasons you may prefer to use a [bind mount](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/) (if you need to directly access the files from outside of Docker; it may be easier to back up and restore the files; ...).  You can also use the `docker run -v` option to bind-mount a host directory into a container, but it brings along its host-system numeric uid owner.  However, notice that the only thing in the image that has the `app` owner is the `data` directory, and the code is otherwise world-readable, so if we set the container to run with the same uid as the host user, this will still work.

```sh
docker run -v "$PWD/data:/app/data" -u $(id -u) ...
```

You should not normally need Docker volumes for your application code (it is contained in the image), nor should you need to build a specific host uid into the image.

Comment: Very informative and appreciated much. Thank you!