# How to give non-root user permission to make and give access to a folder in a Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile, redhat, redhat-containers

I am trying to create/permission to folders using a non-root user using an image from ubi8/ubi-minimal redhat.

Here are two questions:

1. Make a folder:  Another way to give non-user permission to create folders and give permission to folders. I have searched a bit. Could be possible under the `RUN` command after it installs all package with `microdnf`?
2. Give access:  Will `RUN chmod -R 777 /app` is not best practice and best to do `RUN chown -R $USER:$USER /app`?

Here is my Dockerfile which I repeat chown a bit for permission.

```
FROM registry.access.redhat.com/ubi8/ubi-minimal

ENV USER=appuser

RUN microdnf update -y \
    && rm -rf /var/cache/yum \
    && microdnf install gcc wget tar gzip make zlib-devel findutils bzip2-devel openssl-devel ncurses-devel \
       sqlite-devel libffi-devel xz-devel which shadow-utils \
    && microdnf clean all ;\
    useradd -m $USER

RUN chown -R $USER:$USER /opt

RUN mkdir -p /app
RUN chown $USER /app
USER $USER
WORKDIR /app
COPY  . /app/

RUN chown -R $USER:$USER /app
```

Comment: I wrote up a recipe in [Permissions best-practices when using docker exec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69652433/permissions-best-practices-when-using-docker-exec); does this help you?  You should only need write permissions on a dedicated data directory and not your entire application, and if that directory is going to be a host-directory bind mount, you won't know the user owner during the image build.

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel thank you for your link, I saw that link too, is this also applies for ```microdnf```? because I only use ```useradd``` command and not ```adduser```

Comment: I think you meant to notify @DavidMaze, because I didn't provide a link.

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel, my bet yeah sorry about that but @David Maze your link help how things should flow but I am using `microdnf` to `adduser`.